Format number in Angular
I have created an appOnlyNumber directive to just accept input numbers and format them as 'x,xxx,xxx'.
Everything works fine until I send this value to API.
I realize even though the value shown in input is '123,456' after I press '6' from keyboard, but the value to send to API is still '12,3456'.
TS file
@HostListener('input', ['$event'])
onInputChange(event: InputEvent): void {
    this._check(event);
    const element = this._el.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
    element.value = Lib.getFormatNumber(element.value); // Format number: x,xxx,xxx
}

HTML file
<input
    appOnlyNumber
    formControlName="money"
    type="text"
    class="form-control" />

How to fix this issue?

Difficult help without know about your directive, but you should take account that, when we use a directive with a formControl, there're two differents "variables", the "input.value" and the "formControl.value".Check if you change the "input.value" (using some javascript related to the target.value) but not change the formControl.value (you need use setValue method). NOTE: use in .html some like {{yourform.get('money').value}} to check the real value of the formControl.
